# Issue with before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please help me try and understand what is happening here:

I need to approve a nested snippet but when I do it says it cannot find book. I think it may be an issue with the routes because the URL in the browser doesn't match the rake routes.

If someone could hold my hand and explain this as you would to a child :)

> **Couldn't find Book without an ID**

Below is the controller with snippets#approve and the before_filter.

```
   class SnippetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :find_book


   def create
  #raise params.inspect
   @snippet = @book.snippets.create(params[:snippet])
   @snippet.user = current_user
     if @snippet.save
      redirect_to @book
      flash[:success] = "Snippet submitted and awaiting approval."
    else
      flash[:base] = "Someone else has submitted a snippet, please try again later"
      redirect_to @book
   end
 end     


  def approve
   #raise params.inspect
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])
    @snippet.update_attribute(:approved, true)
    redirect_to admins_path

end

  def edit
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])
  end    

  def update
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @snippet.update_attributes(params[:snippet])
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def find_book
    #raise params.inspect
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])


  end
end
```

Now I understand that since I'm doing a post my rake routes says this.

> /books/:book_id/snippets/:id(.:format)

Here is the routes for the custom route:

> active_snippet POST   /snippets/:id/activate(.:format)

This is my custom routes for book && snippet :approval

```
post "books/:id/activate" => "books#approve", :as => "active_book"
  post "snippets/:id/activate" => "snippets#approve", :as => "active_snippet"
```

I've currently got this in my browser ../snippets/2/activate

Erm.... Not sure if I'm thinking correctly.

Comment: is that the only route that shows up? It does not match with the routes you have specified. If it is pointing to the url (snippets/2/activate), only `params[:id]` would be present and any attempt to `find` with `params[:book_id]` would fail as it is nil.

Comment: Ok but I need this filter for other parts of my applications. Could you explain a bit more what I'd need to add to the filter in order for it to pass?

Comment: need to see the rest of your controller code, create is a normal result of a successful POST method. Also there is a difference between a `before` filter and a `before_create` filter. It looks like you are mixing up the conventions.

Comment: Sorry thinking about my model, will add the full controller code.

Comment: I think the problem is in your routes. Could you also add the relevant portions about books and snippets? I assume you have something like `"books/:book_id/snippets/:id"` in there somewhere or maybe a nested resourceful route, which is why you need the before_filter.

Comment: It looks what you need is a `find_snippet` method, and you can get the book using @snippet.book, without the need for `params[:book_id]`

Comment: Could someone post a breakdown please in another answer instead of comments. I'm trying to wrap my head round this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a `POST` request to `snippets/:id/activate` which calls `snippets#approve`.

There is a `before_filter` on the entire `SnippetsController` that calls `find_book` which executes `@book = Book.find(params[:book_id])`. Because your path is `snippets/:id/activate`, `params[:book_id]` is `nil` and hence you are getting that error.

You need to either change your `snippets#approve` path to include the `book_id`, or pass the `book_id` as a `POST` param so that your before filter has access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, appreciate it.